# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't cancel on a touch that isn't already active!'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uitextview

I have an error message when I tap very quickly in a TextView into a TableView. It crashes and gives me the error message :

```
 *** Assertion failure in -[_UIKBRTRecognizer notifyDelegateOfCancelledTouch:],   
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3600.5.2/Keyboard/_UIKBRTRecognizer.m:996

2017-01-14 18:17:18.558043 Formbox_Dacia_BE_Bruxelles_2017[317:15523] 
*** Assertion failure in -[_UIKBRTRecognizer notifyDelegateOfCancelledTouch:], /BuildRoot/Library/

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't cancel on a touch that isn't already active!'
*** First throw call stack:

  (0x1e00ae07 0x1d26b077 0x1e00ace1 0x1e8de0f1 0x236fbeb3 0x236fa3f1 0x3f6d67 0x402ed9 0x3fa215 0x404de1 0x404be9 0x1d866937 0x1d86648c)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type 
    NSException
```

Any ideas ?

EDIT: It seems that it is when I click on the keyboard selection, and I press on a keyboard touch for info.

Comment: I did not understand "I click on the keyboard selection, and I press on a keyboard touch for info".

Comment: I mean, I click on the "little earth" in the keyboard section to change the keyboard from english to french for example, and I touch on the keyboard letters before the keyboard is "fully displayed".

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a solution to this issue? I'm running into the same thing.

Comment: Nope, but I let my collegue checked it. I will check with him if he resolved it tomorrow if you didn't get the solution yet.

Comment: do you got anything @Claudio

Comment: @Anurag Soni @ Eagle11 Hi! I asked to my collegue, and the bug is still present in our apps because it is not something that we can reproduce easily. It is when we change the language keyboard (for example english to french or anything else) during the letters taping. I will investigate it and see if I can find something.

Comment: @ Anurag Soni @Eagle11 I sent the error to Apple to check if there is an answer.